# SecItemCopyMatching - Finding specific kSecClassIdentity by name

Tags: macos, keychain

I'm trying to find a specific entry in my `Mac OS X keychain`, based on it's name (`kSecAttrLabel`), but it looks like `SecItemCopyMatching` is broken and applies no filtering whatsoever when looking for items of type: `kSecClassIdentity`.

This piece of code will return **all** identities found in **all** keychains, despite the `kSecAttrLabel: @"MyIdentity"` parameter:

```
NSDictionary *query = @{ (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge NSString*)kSecClassIdentity,
                     (__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel: @"MyIdentity",
                     (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit: (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll,
                     (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes: @YES,
                     (__bridge id)kSecReturnRef: @YES };

OSStatus status;
status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&privateKey);
```

Granted, I can then find the one identity I'm looking for by filtering manually the returned array, however, beside the fact that, `IMHO`, it should just work, I also would like to remove this identity from my keychain using `SecItemDelete()`, which takes a query as parameter, just like `SecItemCopyMatching`.
If filtering doesn't work for `SecItemCopyMatching`, then it is likely that it won't work for `SecItemDelete` and this mean I will simply erase the content of my keychain if I try to call `SecItemDelete` with this query.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have just found a solution. It was suggested on [on another forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/98029) that

> Using labels on an identity is tricky because identities are not stored in the keychain as an atomic item but are store as a separate private key and certificate, and those items use labels in different ways.

This made me realise that a solution is to search for a certificate by label using `SecItemCopyMatching`, and then create the identity using `SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate`. The latter call should find the matching private key in the Keychain. Here is the full code (in C++) that seems to work for me on macOS Mojave:

```
SecIdentityRef identity = nullptr;
const char* certificateName = ...;
const void* keys[] = {
    kSecClass,
    kSecMatchLimit,
    kSecReturnRef,
    kSecAttrLabel
};
const void* values[] = {
    kSecClassCertificate,
    kSecMatchLimitOne,
    kCFBooleanTrue,
    CFStringCreateWithCString(nullptr, certificateName, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
};
CFDictionaryRef query = CFDictionaryCreate(nullptr, keys, values, 4, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFTypeRef result;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result);
CFRelease(query);
CFRelease(values[3]);
if (status) {
    // error
}
else {
    SecCertificateRef certificate = (SecCertificateRef)result;
    status = SecIdentityCreateWithCertificate(nullptr, certificate, &identity);
    CFRelease(certificate);
    if (status) {
        // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I was using kSecAttrApplicationTag rather than kSecAttrLabel.  I am not an objective c nor an IOS security expert by any means.  It turns out the method I was using to create the lookup tag was incorrect.  Here is what worked for me:

```
- (void) getOrCreateKey: (NSNumber*)bits publicIdentifier:(NSString*)publicID

// no!  This appears in several samples, but did not work for me on iOS
// NSData * publicLookupTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:publicId length:strlen((const char *)publicId)];
//
// yes!
NSData * publicLookupTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:[publicId UTF8String] length:publicId.length];

NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecClassKey                forKey:(id)kSecClass];
[queryPublicKey setObject:publicLookupTag                 forKey:(id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[queryPublicKey setObject:(id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA          forKey:(id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]   forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];

OSStatus lookupStatus = noErr;
lookupStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicLookupKey);
```